# How to find integral : $\int\;\frac {x^2+3}{x^6(1+x^2)}dx$

Tags: integration

**Question:**
How to find integral :
$$\int\;\frac {x^2+3}{x^6(1+x^2)}dx$$
**My attempt**:
\begin{align}
\int\;\frac {x^2+3}{x^6(1+x^2)}dx＝\int\;\frac {x^2＋1＋2}{x^6(1＋x^2)}dx 
& ＝\int\;\frac {x^2＋1}{x^6(1＋x^2)}＋\frac {2}{x^6(1＋x^2)}dx 
\\
&＝\int\;\frac {1}{x^6}dx＋2\int\;\frac {1}{x^6(1＋x^2)}dx
\\
&＝-\frac {1}{x^5}＋2\int\;\frac {1}{x^6(1＋x^2)}dx
\end{align}

I need help calculating this integral

$$\int\;\frac {1}{x^6(1＋x^2)}dx$$

**I appreciate your interest**

Comment: Are you familiar with partial fractions?

Comment: Let $y=\frac1x$
$$\int\;\frac {1}{x^6(1＋x^2)}dx=-\int \frac{(y^2+1-1)^3}{y^2+1}dy$$

Comment: $\frac{1}{2 \cdot 3} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3}$, now do this with functions :-)

Comment: @Dominique appearances are often deceptive :)

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad: you mean "enlightening", not "deceptive" :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle I =\int\frac{1}{x^6(1+x^2)}dx$ , Put $\displaystyle x=\frac{1}{t}$ and $\displaystyle dx=-\frac{1}{t^2}dt$

So $\displaystyle I =-\int\frac{t^6}{1+t^2}dt=-\int \frac{((t^2)^3+1)-1}{1+t^2}dt$

$\displaystyle I =-\int\frac{(t^2)^3+1^3}{1+t^2}dt+\int\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt$

$\displaystyle I =-\int\frac{(t^2+1)(t^4-t^2+1)}{1+t^2}dt+\int\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt$

$\displaystyle I =-\int (t^4-t^2+1)dt+\int\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt$

$\displaystyle I =-\bigg[\frac{t^5}{5}-\frac{t^3}{3}+t\bigg]+\tan^{-1}(t)+C$

Answer (score 3):

$$\int\;\frac {x^2+3}{x^6(1+x^2)}dx
$$ $$=\int\left(-\frac{2}{x^2+1}+\frac{2}{x^2}-\frac{2}{x^4}+\frac{3}{x^6}\right)dx$$

I hope you can continue after this.

Comment: Ok you are lit! How did you split that integral. Could you teach me sis/bro?

Comment: Like is there some shortcut or something?

Comment: @ElizabethHuffman you can refer to lai's answer...the technique is called partial fraction decomposition... it's not as simple as lai did..but yeah you can do this fast when you'll have a lot of practice

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

\begin{aligned}
& \int \frac{x\left(x+3\right)}{x^5\left(1+x^2\right)} dx\\
& \Rightarrow \int \frac{x^2+3}{x^6\left(1+x^2\right)}dx =\int \frac{1+x^2}{\left.1+x^2\right) x^6}dx+\int \frac{2}{x^6\left(1+x^2\right)} dx\\
& \Rightarrow \int \frac{1}{x^6} d x+\int \frac{x}{t^3(1+t)}d t \\
& \Rightarrow \left[ \frac{x^{-6+1}}{-6+1}\right]+\int \frac{dt}{t^{3 / 2}+t^{3 / 2}} \\
& \Rightarrow \frac{x^{-5}}{-5}+\frac{1}{2} \int t^{-3 / 2} d t \\
&= \frac{x^{-5}}{-5}+\frac{1}{2} \frac{t^{\frac{-3}{2}+1}}{-\frac{3}{2}+1} \\
& \Rightarrow \frac{x^{-5}}{5}+\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{t^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{-\frac{1}{2}} \\
&
\end{aligned}
After splitting the integral. I used $t=x^2$

Comment: I don't want to discourage you from posting answers on stackexchange by downvoting you...but here you should write your answers in Latex

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad Ok thank you so much for the kindness. It's the first time I'm posting an answer. I havn't Latex notation yet. But will rewrite the entire thing in Latex for sure. +1 to your comment for being kind.

Comment: @ElizabethHuffman Ma'am I request you to write any question or solution using latex, as it will be searchable and also some devices do not load pictures ma'am.

Comment: @DeeponjitBose Yes I did do as per your request:) Please do upvote if you do like my solution. Cheers!

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad Thank you once again for being kind

Comment: @ElizabethHuffman Yes ma'am thank you very much ma'am, and I upvoted your solution , as you have wished. Your technique works well ma'am.

Comment: @ElizabethHuffman your welcome :)

Comment: Your solution does not seem to be correct. Somehow $\arctan x$ is missing.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{x^2+3}{x^6\left(1+x^2\right)} & =\frac{3 x^2+3-2 x^2}{x^6\left(1+x^2\right)} \\
& =\frac{3}{x^6}-\frac{2}{x^4\left(1+x^2\right)} \\
& =\frac{3}{x^6}-2\left(\frac{1-x^2}{x^4}+\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right) \\
& =\frac{3}{x^6}-\frac{2}{x^4}+\frac{2}{x^2}-\frac{2}{1+x^2}
\end{aligned}
$$
Wish it helps to understand how to resolve the integrand!